# How can I load C header file with IDAPython in IDA Pro?

Tags: idapython

How can I load C header file with IDAPython in IDA Pro?

I'm trying automatically load C header file with IDAPython, such as `Load("filename.h")`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, *w s*'s answer actually points out what you should do. Here I give a more detailed answer:

In short, create file `1.h` under your E: drive, fill with some struct definitions and try this in your IDA's Output Window:

```
idaapi.idc_parse_types("E:\\1.h", idc.PT_FILE)
```

This function will return number of errors it encounters when parsing your `.h` file. If you get 0, it means there is nothing wrong in your header file.

NOTE1: IDA Python keeps changing. The above code works for me (I use IDA Pro 6.8). Some changes may be needed if you use a different version. Try [IDA Python Reference](https://github.com/idapython/bin).

NOTE2: You should find the new types appear in your Local Types window (Press Shift+F1 to open it), which displays the types in TIL. If you actually need structures (which belongs to IDB), try `idaapi.til2idb` or `idaapi.import_type` to import them.

Answer (score 2):

See below the quote from [idc.py](https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/d99a89369741ce272ba792d6f087d0739a2f8ac7/python/idc.py)

```
def parse_decls(inputtype, flags = 0):
    """
    Parse type declarations
    @param inputtype: file name or C declarations (depending on the flags)
    @param flags: combination of PT_... constants or 0
    @return: number of parsing errors (0 no errors)
    """
    return ida_typeinf.idc_parse_types(inputtype, flags)


PT_FILE =   0x0001  # input if a file name (otherwise contains type declarations)
PT_SILENT = 0x0002  # silent mode
PT_PAKDEF = 0x0000  # default pack value
PT_PAK1 =   0x0010  # #pragma pack(1)
PT_PAK2 =   0x0020  # #pragma pack(2)
PT_PAK4 =   0x0030  # #pragma pack(4)
PT_PAK8 =   0x0040  # #pragma pack(8)
PT_PAK16 =  0x0050  # #pragma pack(16)
PT_HIGH  =  0x0080  # assume high level prototypes
                    # (with hidden args, etc)
PT_LOWER =  0x0100  # lower the function prototypes
```